# Select a single active database connection when starting Plone

Tags: python, database, database-connection, plone, psycopg2

I have a Plone 4 site which uses an additional Postgres database via a `Z Psycopg 2 Database Connection` object.  Since the ZODB is sometimes replicated for testing and development purposes, there are a few fellow database connection objects, in a `project_suffix` naming scheme; this way, I can select one of the existing database adapters via `buildout` configuraton script.

However, I noticed that all existing database connection objects are apparently opened when Plone starts up.  I don't know whether this is a real problem (e.g. when applying changes to the schema of the database of another instance), but I'd rather have Plone open *only* the single database which is actually used.  How can I achieve this?

(Plone 4.2.4, Postgres 9.1.9, psycopg2 2.5.1, Debian Linux)

**Update:**
I added some code to the `__init__.py` of my product, which looks roughly like this:

```
from Shared.DC.ZRDB.Connection import Connection
...
dbname = env['DATABASE']
db = None
for id, obj in portalfolder.objectItems():
    if isinstance(obj, Connection):
        if id == dbname:
            db = obj
        else:
            print 'before:', obj._v_connected
            obj._v_database_connection.close()
            print 'after: ', obj._v_connected
```

However, this seems not to work; there are no exceptions I'm aware of, but for both `before` and `after`, I get a timestamp, and when looking in the ZMI afterwards, the connections seem to be open.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this. You are assumed to actually need and use the connection objects that exist.

Comment: That's a pity. Sounds like I'll need to iterate the database objects in portal root and close those which are not configure to be _the used one_ ...